# How to set new manufacture on RANCID?

Tags: networking, router, network-monitoring

I'm trying to monitor a Lenovo switch using `rancid`, as there's no default scripts for that manufacture, I had to create my own one. The problem comes when trying to set up the config so it executes `slenovo` script when running on a Lenovo system.

../var/Routers/router.db

```
1.2.3.4;lenovo;up;
```

~./cloginrc

```
add user 1.2.3.4 foo
add noenable 1.2.3.4 {0}
add password 1.2.3.4       {bar}        {bar}
add method 1.2.3.4 ssh
```

../etc/rancid.types.conf

```
lenovo;login;clogin
lenovo;script;slenovo
```

Error message:

```
Trying to get all of the configs.
unknown router manufacturer for 1.2.3.4: lenovo
```

I'm a bit new to rancid so I might be forgetting something crucial but that's what I found on the documentation.